# Jax and train Neural Networks

Tags: python, neural-network, jax

I am a beginner in JAX and I am trying to learn how to train a neural network. I saw some blogs, but as I understood there isn't a library that you can train it easily, like 'fit' as in sklearn. I am interested about classification task, could you please reccommend me any blogs in order to adopt his/her algorithm into my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JAX is an array manipulation library, not a deep learning library: in that respect, you should think of it as more similar to NumPy than similar to scikit-learn. If you want neural networks built on JAX, there are several other good projects available such as [haiku](https://github.com/deepmind/dm-haiku) and [flax](https://github.com/google/flax).